# Are there any English translations of Madhva's and Ramanuja's Gita Bhasya?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request, ramanujacharya, book-recommendation, madhvacharya

I'm looking for English Translations of Ramanuja's and Madhvacharya's Gita commentaries in physical/printed book format.

Are there any English translation of Ramanuja's Gita Bhasya, **other than the one by Swami Adidevananda**? I would prefer a translation of a monk/scholar who is connected to the Sri Sampradayan order, since i think they're the ones who'll be able to describe Ramanuja's Gita interpretations in a genuine manner.

When it comes to Gita bhasya of Madhvacharya, I can't find any in English that's available for purchase in actual book format.

Comment: For Hindi, there's a book available from Gitapress for Ramanujacharya's Bhashya

Comment: One [book](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/ramanuja_gita_bhashya.pdf) is available from [srimatham.org](http://www.srimatham.com/our-publications.html)

Comment: @Pandya - http://vishnudut1926.blogspot.com/2018/02/sri-ramanuja-gita-bhasya-devanagari-and.html

Comment: Search for BNK Sharma's translation of Madhva's commentary and Sampatkumaran of Ramanuja's.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, For Ramanujacharya's Bhashya on Srimad Bhagvad Gita, there's one good book available:

- The Gitabhashya of Ramamuja, **translated by M. R. Sampath kumaran**, published by Anantacharya Indological Research Institute 1988.

  [image: The Gitabhashya of Ramanujacharya]

  You can purchase the physical book or read/get it from [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/BhagavadGitaBhashyaRamanunujaGitaBhashyaOfRamanujaSampatkumaranM.R.)
- The English translation of Madhvacharya's Bhashya on Bhagvad Gita is available at [here](http://nageshsonde.com/bhagavad_gita.pdf)

Comment: Is the physical book available for purchase online? I checked Amazon but it's not listed there. Any other site?

Answer (score 2):

This is the link to Madhavacharya's Gita Bhashya translated by B.N.K. Sharma -

https://archive.org/details/bhagavadgitabhasyaofsrimadhvacaryabnksharma1989ocr

This book was published in 1989 in Bangalore by Anandatirtha Pratisthana.

One more translation is also available online. This is done by Prof. GV Nadgouda. Here is the link -

https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/sanskrit-bhagavadgita-englishmeaning13072016.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Maximum commentries of all the well known acharyas can be found on [gitasupersite by IITK](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1)

Answer (score 0):

For Ramanuja’s Gita Bhasya, I prefer the translation by Svāmī Ādidevānanda which you can read at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/BhagavadGitaSriRamanujaGitaBhashyaSwamiAdidevanandaR.K.MuttMS). You can buy the physical book, just search on google using the ISBN: 9788178235189.

Comment: OP specified that he is looking for one besides Swami Adidevananda's translation.

Comment: Oh my mistake I did not read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Bhagavad Gita Bhashya And Tatparya Nirnaya Of Madhvacharya Nagesh Sonde D. https://archive.org/details/BhagavadGitaBhashyaAndTatparyaNirnayaOfMadhvacharyaNageshSondeD.FromInternet/page/n3/mode/2up